# Create Gradle task to export Android source as .zip file

Tags: android, build, zip, gradle

I have already tried to do this with the Gradle Zip task like this:

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from sourceSets*.allSource
}
```

But even if the build process from command line was successful, there is no .zip file in my build folder after the process has finished. Does anybody know what's wrong with my code? I am not really experienced with groovy, so maybe I made a very stupid mistake...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `assemble.dependsOn = srcZip`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Should I add this assignment inside of the function? When I use the assignment after the function there is the following error: 'Cannot cast object 'task ':srcZip'' with class 'org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip_Decorated' to class 'java.lang.Iterable''

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for unclear comment with error. Try add this to you `build.gradle`:

```
assemble.dependsOn srcZip
```

Now when you run assemble it will zip your source code.

Small addition that your zip task needs correction:

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from android.sourceSets*.allSource
    from android.sourceSets*.resource
}
```

Comment: Okay, great. Now when I run gradle assemble, I get a zip file. Thanks! But that is not exactly what I wanted. I need all my project stuff to be in this zip file, so that I can build an apk from it. The zip file I get is only 145kb. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: What staff do you need? Why not to use tag in VCS?

Comment: I need all resources, java files and assets for the CI to build an apk file.

Comment: So you running build.gradle locally and after you send zip file to CI?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do for now.

Comment: Last question - why not to checkout project from VCS instead of using zip files?

Comment: I use git but I also want to try it like this.

Comment: Added resources but I don't know yet how to include android manifest. But it should be possible

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Eugen. This solution works for me:

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
from projectDir
exclude 'build'
}
```

You can add all further files and directories to exclude, that you don't want to get zipped.